# Javascript - angularjs - open outlook

Tags: angularjs, outlook

With Angularjs is it possible to open outlook and attach a file to the email we ask outlook to send?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get it done? If yes, add in a comment please

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using JavaScript only in Internet Explorer and if the site is a Trusted Site and ActiveX objects are enabled. See [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajnishkaushik/archive/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007.aspx) for the sample code.